# SQL Select from multiple tables and count third

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, outer-join

I want to count number of rows in table that is referenced by two fields of other tables.

I've the following structure

```
branches table
id, name
1, dev
2, master

levels table
id, name
1, easy
2, hard

repos table
id, name, branch_id, level_id
1, repo-1, 1, 1
2, repo-2, 2, 2
```

Result that I want to achieve

```
b_id, l_id, r_cnt
1, 1, 1
1, 2, 0
2, 1, 0
2, 2, 1
```

The statement that I've tried, but getting error at right join

```
SELECT
    b.id,
    l.id,
    COUNT(r)
FROM
    branches b,
    levels l
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN repos r ON r.branch_id = b.id
    AND r.level_id = l.id;
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quite close. Main problems with your query:

- you are mixing implicit and explicit joins: just don't. Explicit joins are evaluated first, causing the error that you are getting (implicit joined tables are not yet identified)
- you want a `right join`, not a `left join`; `right join` are quite counter-intuitive, I would recommend avoiding them in general

Consider:

```
select b.id b_id, l.id l_id, count(r.id)
from branches b
cross join levels l
left join repos r on r.branch_id = b.id and r.level_id = l.id
group by b.id, l.id
```

This works by generating all possible combinations of `branches` and `levels` using a `cross join` (that's basically a cartesian product of both tables), and then bringing the `repos` table with a `left join`. The rest is aggregation and counting how many `repos` records match each branch/level combination.

Comment: thank you! what would be the best way to convert count to bool? isn't count(r.id)::int::boolean a code smell?

Comment: Welcome @EvgeniyPetrov. `count(*)::boolean` should do it.